# sqoop export failed- Export job failed

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

Hi I am trying to run the sqoop export command. There is an empty table called empolyee in mysql under the username newuser and the database is db. I have created a csv file by taking care of the datatypes that the table employee in mysql has. I have put that file in the hdfs directory called /sqoop/export/emp.csv. I have checked the file in hdfs. It is present in that directory. Then I have run the export command as

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db --username newuser --table employee --export-dir /sqoop/export/emp.csv --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

It is mapping 100% and then I am getting the error as Export job failed as in

```
20/06/26 15:18:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
20/06/26 15:18:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1593163228066_0003 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1593163228066_0003_m_000003
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

20/06/26 15:18:38 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Killed map tasks=3
        Launched map tasks=4
        Data-local map tasks=4
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=23002
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=23002
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=23002
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=23554048
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
20/06/26 15:18:38 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
20/06/26 15:18:38 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 22.6316 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
20/06/26 15:18:38 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Exported 0 records.
20/06/26 15:18:38 ERROR mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Export job failed!
20/06/26 15:18:38 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Error during export: 
Export job failed!
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase.runExport(ExportJobBase.java:445)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.exportTable(SqlManager.java:931)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.exportTable(ExportTool.java:80)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ExportTool.run(ExportTool.java:99)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

So, what may be the problem and how could I fix this? Thanks

Comment: check job log for this `job_1593163228066_0003`. If possible post the error log here also

Comment: It is saying to check failed map task logs. But this is not given in stderrlog, it is given is syslog- Can't export data, please check failed map task logs. In stderrlog, it is warning that- log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. --@Snigdhajyoti Please help

Comment: Please check if input field seperated by `,`(comma) or it has any other value like space in your CSV file. If possible please provide the some of the rows. I can try on my end.

Comment: Ohh there was a single space in my csv file. That was the problem. I have corrected that and now it is working fine. Thankyou so much @Snigdhajyoti